# How to curve an edge inside the mesh?

Tags: mesh

I want to make a window with a half-circle-top. How do i round the top edge of the window?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first subdivide the top line, change to proportional editing -> sphere, grab the middle vertex and move it to the tob. Scroll the mouse wheel to adjust size of your influence circle.

[image]

Comment: It's funny that a small misstep wasn't giving me the desired result with the same step that you're doing here. I did the same but instead of selecting the outer edge vetices, I selected the inner vertices and wasn't getting the proper curve. Finally ended up using the spin tool and doing a lot of geometry re routing. So Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome! It happened to me so often - just one single mistake when you watch a tutorial - and it might be completely messed up. I learnt it the hard way ;)